# Prevent downloading files to not logged in users with CollectionFS

Tags: file, meteor, download

As is said here https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#security, there is "donwload", a custom type of allow/deny function. I am trying to prevent not logged in users to download uploaded files like this:

```
Avatars.allow({
    download: function(userId, file) {
        if(userId) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? I tried to set the allow/deny function as yours and found out that the userId is always 'undefined' wheather  I am logged in or not. Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, userId is always 'undefined'.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, may you can define a ticket on github?

Comment: Already did it. https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/449 Looks like no one cares.

Comment: Hey, I'm from the future. Apparently people did care on the bug report. You thanked @nooitaf there, but the actual cause/change needed was not clearly stated. Care to summarize? Thanks.

Comment: Huh, that was long time ago. If I remember correctly the userId is based on that token which CollectionFS generates. It behaves as a session token, but I might be wrong. This was really really long time ago. I am not that much into Meteor anymore.